# How can I test my express rest api built with MikroORM?

Tags: typescript, rest, express, jestjs, mikro-orm

**index.ts:**

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import express from 'express'
import { EntityManager, EntityRepository, MikroORM, RequestContext } from '@mikro-orm/core'
import options from '../mikro-orm.config'
import { Music } from './entities/music.entity'
import router from './routes'

const app = express()

export const DI = {} as {
    orm: MikroORM,
    em: EntityManager,
    musicRepository: EntityRepository<Music>
}

async function bootstrap() {

    DI.orm = await MikroORM.init(options)

    DI.em = DI.orm.em
    DI.musicRepository = DI.orm.em.getRepository(Music)

    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use((req, res, next) => RequestContext.create(DI.orm.em, next))
    app.use(router)

    return { app, DI }

}

bootstrap()

export default bootstrap
```

**music.test.ts**

```
import request from 'supertest'
import bootstrap from '../index'

describe('musics', () => {

    it('should search the musics', async () => {

        const { DI, app } = await bootstrap()
    request(app)
        .get('/musics')
        .expect(200)
        .end()

    await DI.orm.close()

})
```

})

I mean, i would like to close the connection after all tests end, but i can not do this because the ORM connections is returned by the function bootstrap, that can only be called inside the "it" scope.

Can anyone help me to do something like this?

```
describe('musics', () => {

    afterAll(async () => {
        await DI.orm.close()
    })

    it('should search the musics', async () => {

        const { DI, app } = await bootstrap()

        request(app)
            .get('/musics')
            .expect(200)
            .end()

    })

})
```

the repository is: https://github.com/brenomacedo/g-track/tree/master/backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `beforeAll` hook to create the connection, and store the result in the outer scope:

```
describe('musics', () => {

    let context: any = {}; // TODO type this properly

    beforeAll(async () => {
        context = await bootstrap()
    })

    afterAll(async () => {
        await context.DI.orm.close()
    })

    it('should search the musics', async () => {
        request(context.app)
            .get('/musics')
            .expect(200)
            .end()

    })

})
```

Comment: hey, thank you,it solved my question, but jest is still throwing the message "Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.", its like the connection were not closed. do you know why is this happening?

Comment: afaik jest v27 does this, and it will be probably a false positive warning or an issue with jest, as with v26 it works just fine (at least that is how it behaves in the orm tests)